# Why does the JProfiler package contain the libstdc++ and libexpatlibs libraries?

Tags: libstdc++, jprofiler

I see that JProfiler comes with libstdc++ and libexpat in the library folder. Also, the standard location libraries will be loaded first since agent(libjprofilerti) is loaded later.

ldd -v  says that depend on the libraries which is packaged.

Why are these libraries included?

Answer (score 0):

On some older Linux distributions these libraries are not installed by default, so they are included with the JProfiler agent. On modern Linux distributions it would indeed not be necessary to bundle these libraries.